# Como setar o indice de um spinner?

Tags: android, spinners

Eu tenho 3 spinners que estou utilizando para filtros, na minha aplicação cada coluna tem um filtro, nome, idade, cidade, quando eu clicar no filtro idade, vou escolher uma idade, por exemplo 12 e a idade vai ficar selecionada, quando eu clicar em cidade preciso que o valor selecionado no idade volte para o primeiro índice do spinner que é "idade". Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Adicione o que você já fez na pergunta, para facilitar as respostas.

Comment: O spinner possui o método [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int)). Com ele podemos selecionar o índice de um spinner.